# How to make parent window invisible when launching dialog

Tags: python, window, visibility, pyside

I am newbie in Gui Programming. I am using PySide.
What i wanted to ask is there a way to make the parent window invisible when a dialog box is launched from the main window.
Also how to make the window reappear on exiting from the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All widgets have [hide](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide) and [show](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show) functions that can be used to achieve what you want:

```
    parent.hide()
    dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    dialog.exec_()
    parent.show()
```